# How to properly refresh a list while using it for iterating

Tags: java, json, list

I have the following problem. I am deleting some firewall rules from a SonicWall. The way I do this is to get all the rules from the sonic wall find the matching ones, store them in a list and use this list in order to issue the command to delete them. The way the rules are delete is by using SSH and a command with their ID. The problem I am having is that every time an ID is deleted then all the ID's are changed leading always the second command to try and delete an access rule that does not exist (or even worse is the wrong one). I order to overcome this, after each delete process I refresh the list I order to get the renewed elements and thus their new ID's. The problem I am facing is that the update of the list is not correct (it happens within the for each loop) since the list is used as an iterator (leading to wrong commands being issued).

What is best and safest way to update this list with new elements?

Below is the part of code in question:

```
multiResult = expect.expect(anyOf(regexp("(.*)" + promptPattern)));     
        accessRules = getAccessRules(multiResult, accessRule);
        if(accessRules == null){
            Trc.trc("No access rules found to delete");
            return false;
        }

        numberOfRulesToDelete = accessRules.size();
        int size = numberOfRulesToDelete;
        IntList deleteRulesId = new IntList();

        while(numberOfRulesToDelete != 0){
            for(AccessRule arToDelete : accessRules){
            expect.sendLine("configure");
            multiResult = expect.expect(anyOf(regexp("(.*)" + confmodePromptPattern)));
            Result showCmdResult = multiResult.getResults().get(0);
            GenericCmdDto outPut = null;
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            GenericFailedCmdDto failedOutPut = null;
            String swResponse = null;

            swResponse = handleSWConfModeResponse(showCmdResult);
            outPut = objectMapper.readValue(createSuccessfullJSONResponse(swResponse.getBytes()), GenericCmdDto.class);
            if(outPut.getSuccess()){//if change to configure command was successfull
                Result confCmdResult = null;
                Trc.trc("Configure command: " + outPut.getSuccess());
                expect.sendLine("no access-rule id "  + arToDelete.getIndex());
                MultiResult confResult = expect.expect(anyOf(regexp("(.*)" + confmodePromptPattern)));
                confCmdResult = confResult.getResults().get(0);

                swResponse = handleSWConfModeResponse(confCmdResult);
                outPut = objectMapper.readValue(createSuccessfullJSONResponse(swResponse.getBytes()), GenericCmdDto.class);
                if(outPut.getSuccess()){//if the delete command was successfull
                Trc.trc("Delete command issued successfully");
                expect.sendLine("commit");
                confCmdResult = expect.expect(anyOf(regexp("(.*)" + confmodePromptPattern)));

                swResponse = handleSWConfModeResponse(confCmdResult);
                outPut = objectMapper.readValue(createSuccessfullJSONResponse(swResponse.getBytes()), GenericCmdDto.class);
                if(outPut.getSuccess()){//if the commit command was successfull
                    Trc.trc("Commit command issued succesfully!");
                    Trc.trc("Deleted successfully access rule: " + arToDelete.getIndex());
                    deleteRulesId.addElement(arToDelete.getIndex());

                    expect.sendLine("exit");//change to no conf mode
                    confCmdResult = expect.expect(anyOf(regexp("(.*)" + promptPattern)));

                    swResponse = handleSWPromptModeResponse(confCmdResult);
                    outPut = objectMapper.readValue(createSuccessfullJSONResponse(swResponse.getBytes()), GenericCmdDto.class);
                    if(outPut.getSuccess()){//if the exit command was successfull
                    Trc.trc("Exit command issued successfully!");
                    operationSuccess = outPut.getSuccess();
                    }else{//if exit unsucessfull                
                    failedOutPut = objectMapper.readValue(createFailedJSONResponse(swResponse.getBytes()), GenericFailedCmdDto.class);
                    operationSuccess = outPut.getSuccess();
                    Trc.trc("Commit command has failed! Message: " + failedOutPut.getMessage() + ", Code: " + failedOutPut.getCode());
                    Trc.trc("Changing to show mode....");
                    expect.sendLine("exit");
                    multiResult = expect.expect(anyOf(regexp("(.*)" + promptPattern)));
                    showCmdResult = multiResult.getResults().get(0);

                    swResponse = handleSWPromptModeResponse(confCmdResult);

                    outPut = objectMapper.readValue(createSuccessfullJSONResponse(swResponse.getBytes()), GenericCmdDto.class);
                    if(outPut.getSuccess()){
                        Trc.trc("Exiting from conf mode..");
                        Trc.trc("Exit command: " + outPut.getSuccess());
                    }
                    return operationSuccess;
                    }
                }else{//if commit unsucessfull
                    failedOutPut = objectMapper.readValue(createFailedJSONResponse(swResponse.getBytes()), GenericFailedCmdDto.class);
                    operationSuccess = outPut.getSuccess();
                    Trc.trc("Commit command has failed! Message: " + failedOutPut.getMessage() + ", Code: " + failedOutPut.getCode());
                    Trc.trc("Changing to show mode....");
                    expect.sendLine("exit");
                    multiResult = expect.expect(anyOf(regexp("(.*)" + promptPattern)));
                    showCmdResult = multiResult.getResults().get(0);

                    swResponse = handleSWPromptModeResponse(showCmdResult);
                    outPut = objectMapper.readValue(createSuccessfullJSONResponse(swResponse.getBytes()), GenericCmdDto.class);
                    if(outPut.getSuccess()){
                    Trc.trc("Exiting from conf mode..");
                    Trc.trc("Exit command: " + outPut.getSuccess());
                    }
                    return operationSuccess;
                }
                }else{//if delete unsucessfull
                failedOutPut = objectMapper.readValue(createFailedJSONResponse(swResponse.getBytes()), GenericFailedCmdDto.class);
                operationSuccess = outPut.getSuccess();
                Trc.trc("Commit command has failed! Message: " + failedOutPut.getMessage() + ", Code: " + failedOutPut.getCode());
                Trc.trc("Changing to show mode....");
                expect.sendLine("exit");
                multiResult = expect.expect(anyOf(regexp("(.*)" + promptPattern)));
                showCmdResult = multiResult.getResults().get(0);

                swResponse = handleSWPromptModeResponse(showCmdResult);
                outPut = objectMapper.readValue(createSuccessfullJSONResponse(swResponse.getBytes()), GenericCmdDto.class);
                if(outPut.getSuccess()){
                    Trc.trc("Exiting from conf mode..");
                    Trc.trc("Exit command: " + outPut.getSuccess());
                }
                return operationSuccess;
                }

            }
            else{//if configure unsuccessfull
                failedOutPut = objectMapper.readValue(createFailedJSONResponse(swResponse.getBytes()), GenericFailedCmdDto.class);
                operationSuccess = outPut.getSuccess();
                Trc.trc("Commit command has failed! Message: " + failedOutPut.getMessage() + ", Code: " + failedOutPut.getCode());
                Trc.trc("Changing to show mode....");
                expect.sendLine("exit");
                multiResult = expect.expect(anyOf(regexp("(.*)" + promptPattern)));
                showCmdResult = multiResult.getResults().get(0);

                swResponse = handleSWPromptModeResponse(showCmdResult);
                outPut = objectMapper.readValue(createSuccessfullJSONResponse(swResponse.getBytes()), GenericCmdDto.class);
                if(outPut.getSuccess()){
                Trc.trc("Exiting from conf mode..");
                Trc.trc("Exit command: " + outPut.getSuccess());
                }
                return operationSuccess;
            }     
            expect.sendLine("show access-rules from " + accessRule.getFromZone() + " to " + accessRule.getToZone());
            multiResult = expect.expect(anyOf(regexp("(.*)" + promptPattern)));
            accessRules = getAccessRules(multiResult, accessRule);
            if(accessRules != null){
                numberOfRulesToDelete = accessRules.size();
            }else{
                Trc.trc("Deleting process complete!");
                numberOfRulesToDelete = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < deleteRulesId.size(); i++){
                Trc.trc("Deleted " + size + " successfully rules: " + deleteRulesId.getElementAt(i));
                }
            }
            }  
        }
        return operationSuccess;
```

Comment: Please strip away the irrelevant parts of the code and create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that shows the problem.

Comment: I agree with Keppil that the code seems to contain too much irrelevant parts for the question but besides that you could try and use an iterator directly (using `hasNext()` and `next()` to iterate) and call `remove()` on the iterator for elements that need to be removed. If there are new elements that might be inserted where the iterator has already been this might be a problem, so don't add new elements while iterating. (If just the ids change and the order is constant that shouldn't be a problem).

Answer (score 1):

You should not update a list while iterate through it.

Use a copy instead.

Answer (score 0):

Would it help you to use the iterator of the list. You can use the iterator delete method and remove the item from the list immediately.

Comment: I have considered this but how would this be helpful? I mean you get a response from the SonicWall the first time that is used to determine the number of elements an init the list with them. Then you use the first element's id to delete it. Then you refresh the list and by default you have an element less. I don't see why I should remove it from the list since it's not going to exist when the list is refreshed.

Comment: In the end I modified the method in question not to include the loop as it was not needed. But it would be nice to see an definite answer on how one could do what I asked.